# How to fix : "Microsoft (r) developer studio has stopped working" in VC6

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm designing an MFC interface application, it throws the following error:
`Microsoft (r) developer studio has stopped working`

**Ex:** If I drag a `tabControl` from the toolbar to the windows design area;
when I right click to change some properties and events, it throws this error:

[image]

How does one fix it?
I'm using `Windows 7 Ultimate x64`.
I'm tried it in `Windows XP` and it showed me the same error.

Comment: VC 6 is 14 years old.  Have you tried it in the latests version of VC which is free.

Comment: Oh, yes.But I'm have a big application (from 2001). Now I want to change some part (small) of it,I need some time to Redesgin this in VS2008 or VS2010
Do you have any ideal for this cases ?
Thank !

Comment: I think at this point you have to consider that part of the code is brittle and the tools are brittle too. The best thing I think would be to isolate the code you need to change into a DLL and then perhaps replace it with some more modern code using more modern tools. **Unless you have great regression test infrastructure I would be very very hesitant of touching such old code with out a great deal care.**

Comment: In addition to right-clicking to get the properties, you can also configure VC6 to show the properties when you double-click on a widget. Try that.